# Wish or Hope; what suits here?

Tags: word-choice

If you could let me know what clause fits the situation: A wants to be with B after death; i.e. A wishes to be in heavens with B. This is for future and something that `A is not certain` about, whether he'll be able to be with B or not, he `only can wish` so during the life hence now what is the best:
a) I wish I could be with B in heavens.
b) I hope I will be  with B in heavens.
c) I wish I were with B in heavens.
d) I wish to be with B in heavens.
Note that the **wish is possible** to come true but **is not certain** to come true...

Answer (score 2):

I think what you’re asking here is actually deeper than a question of language.

Hoping is more than wishing. Hope is a state of mind and of spirit, with a more positive expectation and anticipation of the desired outcome.

Wishing does not necessarily require any reasonable expectation that the desired outcome could ever actually occur. One can wish for something that they know is impossible, but they can only hope for something they believe IS possible. Thus “I wish I could go back in time” makes sense, but “I hope I can go back in time sounds stupid, as though one were actually expecting to be able to go back in time.

Because one can wish for something impossible, “wish” can take on a somewhat negative meaning as a futile and fruitless activity, as in “That’s wishful thinking.”

“Wish” to me is more episodic than “hope.” One “wishes” at a particular time, in a particular place, for a particular thing, and then their wish is over. Frequently the act of wishing is all one does in making a wish. Hoping, on the other hand, usually endures until the desired outcome happens or is rendered impossible, and is frequently accompanied by actions to bring about the desired outcome. “I hope to be with her in heaven, so I’ll be steadfast and pure on earth.” “I wish I could be with her in Heaven” sounds more helpless and passive, as though the speaker has no power over the result at all.

I think because A believes in Heaven, and probably continually wants and anticipates being with B there after death, that A’s sentence should be:

“I hope to be with B in Heaven.”

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, `d) I wish to be with B in heavens.` would be the best among the options.

Not `a) I wish I could be with B in heavens.` because it sounds like an excuse. e.g. I could be with B but I got something else to do at that time etc.

Not `b) I hope I will be with B in heavens.`: because it sounds too much definitive. As you said, it is a future event which is kind of uncertain.

Not `c) I wish I were with B in heavens.`: because it sounds like feeling a guilt. e.g. In the retrospect, I was not with B in heavens. `OR` Unfortunately I didn't get to be with B in heavens.

Comment: @ZeeshanSiddiqii This is not a discussion forum. Unless this is related to your original question, you should be opening a separate new question.